# Pass formset as an argument to a function in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to pass a formset as an argument to a function and want to validate the formset. If the question is not correct somebody please correct the question.

This is my function:

```
def valid_check(*args):
    valid = True
    for arg in args:
        if not arg.is_valid():
            valid = False
    return valid 

valid = valid_check(form1,formset1,formset2)
    if valid:
        #do something
```

But this not working and showing this error:

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your forgot to output [`management_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform)s in your html template or to add the [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) to the formsets:

```
formset1 = FormSet1(prefix='formset1')
formset2 = FormSet2(prefix='formset2')
```

And then in the template:

```
{{ formset1.management_form }}
{{ formset2.management_form }}
```

**UPDATE**: to the question asked in the comments:

Never use the `if form.is_valid() and formset1.is_valid:` statement. If the `form` is invalid then the `formset` validation will not run.  So your `valid_check()` function is much more correct solution - it checks all passed forms/formsets.

But I prefer to use the python's built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
if all([form.is_valid(), formset1.is_valid(), formset2.is_valid()]):
```

In this case `is_valid()` is called for each form/formset in the list construction and `all()` returns `True` only if all forms are valid.

Comment: let me ask a doubt..which method is good ..writing a function ( example above function  ) to  validate the 4 formset or using 
if form.is_valid() and formset1.is_valid and  and formset.is_valid():

Comment: thanks a lot for your valuable answer and for your valuable time. :-)